# "The method toCharArray() is undefined for the type Scanner"

Tags: java, arrays, char

I am trying to reverse a `String` inputted by the user, but I am receiving this error when I run the program:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
   The method toCharArray() is undefined for the type Scanner
```

Why am I getting this error? Here's my program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public abstract class StringReverse {
    public abstract char[] toCharArray();
    private static Scanner input;

    public static <string> void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        Scanner String = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = input.next();
        char[] strArray = input.toCharArray();

        for (int i = strArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            System.out.print(strArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: change to `char[] strArray = str.toCharArray();`

Comment: I don't know how much clearer the exception could possibly be...

Comment: and change `Scanner String = new Scanner(System.in);` to `input = new Scanner(System.in);`

Comment: new StringBuilder("true").reverse().toString();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple minor issues with your code, causing it not to run correctly:

1. change `Scanner String = new Scanner(System.in);` to `input = new Scanner(System.in);`
2. change `char[] strArray = input.toCharArray();` to `char[] strArray = str.toCharArray();`
3. This line: `public abstract char[] toCharArray();` is useless, you can just delete it (This is not incorrect, but it is not necessary).
4. Also, you can remove `<string>` from the main method header, as it is useless.

So your final code should look like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public abstract class StringReverse {
    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = input.next();
        char[] strArray = str.toCharArray();

        for (int i = strArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            System.out.print(strArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Or the even easier way to reverse a string, is to use a `StringBuilder()` and `.reverse()`, like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public abstract class StringReverse {
    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = input.next();
        System.out.println(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString());
    }
}
```